# Adding dynamically to qml tabbar and stacklayout

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'm trying to create a tabbed pages in qml. I used TabBar associated with StackLayout:

```
      TabBar {
      id: bar
      width: parent.width
      TabButton {
          text: qsTr("Home")
      }
      TabButton {
          text: qsTr("Discover")
      }
      TabButton {
          text: qsTr("Activity")
      }
  }

  StackLayout {
      width: parent.width
      currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
      Item {
          id: homeTab
      }
      Item {
          id: discoverTab
      }
      Item {
          id: activityTab
      }
  }
```

A new tabButton can be easily added by this code dynamically:

```
        var tab = tabButton.createObject(TTabButton, {text: tabName});
        bar.addItem(tab);
```

which TTabButton is a separate file consisting TabButton item. But I can't find any ways to add a new page to StackLayout. It seems it is supposed to be static. So my question is how to have dynamic tab-paged in qml?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add to the children of StackLayout:

```qml
var item = stackItem.createObject(null, {id: "tabName"})
layout.children.push(item)
```

Where `stackItem` is the Component of those items you add to your StackLayout `layout`.

Answer (score 3):

You can manipulate the `children` (or `data`) property of the `StackLayout` directly as suggested, but potentially a better idea is to use a `Repeater` in conjunction with an `ObjectModel`:

```
StackLayout
{
    id: stackLayout
    currentIndex: bar.currentIndex
        
    Repeater
    {
        model: ObjectModel
        {
            id: container
        }
    }
}
```

This way you get the much richer and easier API of `ObjectModel`:

```
let tabPage = tabPageComponent.createObject(stackLayout);
container.append(tabPage);

let tabPage2 = tabPageComponent.createObject(stackLayout);
container.insert(0, tabPage2);

container.move(1, 0);
// etc.
```

One important detail here is that when removing a tab, it's necessary to manually `destroy()` it, since the `Repeater`/`ObjectModel` only manages the hierarchy, not lifetime.

```
let tabPage = container.get(0);
container.remove(0);
tabPage.destroy();
```

Comment: This should be the preferred way of doing it. Otherwise, object destruction and removal become messy.